# How do I use the pivot longer function in R with different col specifications?

Tags: r, pivot, tibble

I'm working with a dataset from github with 8 variables and just wanted to tidy it for now, so I tried the pivot_longer function like this:

```
corona_data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/time-series-19-covid-combined.csv")
glimpse(corona_data)    
pivot_longer(-Country/Region, names_to = "Date", values_to = "values") %>%
```

I want to create a tibble by column with the variables of the countries, the Date and the Confirmed and Recovered Cases and Deaths.
I tried all kinds of variations of this function and I keep getting an error about different column specifications.
I'm a bloody beginner with R so I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

corona_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(`Country/Region`, Date, Lat, Long, `Province/State`), names_to = "Name", values_to = "values")
```

To have only Confirmed cases you can use

```
corona_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(`Country/Region`, Date, Lat, Long, `Province/State`), names_to = "Name", values_to = "values") %>% 
  subset(Name == "Confirmed")
```

Similarly you can get the data for Recovered and Deaths.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach if you only want Confirmed, Recovered and Death cases:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
#Data
corona_data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/time-series-19-covid-combined.csv")
#Code
corona_data %>% select(c(1,2,6,7,8)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(1,2)) %>%
  arrange(name,`Country/Region`,Date)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 185,136 x 4
   Date       `Country/Region` name      value
   <date>     <chr>            <chr>     <dbl>
 1 2020-01-22 Afghanistan      Confirmed     0
 2 2020-01-23 Afghanistan      Confirmed     0
 3 2020-01-24 Afghanistan      Confirmed     0
 4 2020-01-25 Afghanistan      Confirmed     0
 5 2020-01-26 Afghanistan      Confirmed     0
 6 2020-01-27 Afghanistan      Confirmed     0
 7 2020-01-28 Afghanistan      Confirmed     0
 8 2020-01-29 Afghanistan      Confirmed     0
 9 2020-01-30 Afghanistan      Confirmed     0
10 2020-01-31 Afghanistan      Confirmed     0
# ... with 185,126 more rows
```

Comment: @lena_sr If you think this answer was useful you could upvote it, as long as you have accepted an answer that fits your expectations :)

Comment: I did upvote it but apparently "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score", thats what it tells me. I actually tried to accept both your answers because they were equally useful, so thanks again :)